# Getting your voice heard on out of scope problems

Tags: communication, project-management, international

The situation:
I work for a large European based multinational corporation on an IT implementation.  I am based out of the only major North American location.  My project is presently unfeasable due to very poor load times due to factors out of scope of my project.  I have presented head office with the issue and have been CCed on much of the conversation regarding the solution(out of courtesy rather than requirement).  I am concerned that the infrastructure department has taken bits and pieces of the problem data and come up with a very expensive solution that ignores many of the aspects of the issue.  I am concerned that this will be a time consuming dead end that will negatively impact (possibly kill) the project that I have been specifically hired to do.  I have addressed the issue with a head office peer and they stated that the network expert made his recommendations and they are being considerred.

Present course of action:
Presently I am awaiting an answer from a South American counterpart as to why they are able to achieve 800% better file load speed when infrastructure differences would predict 50% better file load speed.  I feel like once I know their solution I can hold up a working model of what could be done.

Question:
I have no authority over this but would like my concerns addressed by upper management on another continent.

What are some strategies for having your voice heard in situations out of scope for your position?  What are some strategies for challenging the conclusions of area experts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are some strategies for having your voice heard in situations out of scope for your position?

Work through your management as much as possible. Work with them as much as you can. You want to use their access and their authority as leverage and hotel room master key. Since you are in charge of the implementation, then you are speaking as the problem domain expert on the implementation. There are times when you have no authority but that of your own voice. That's OK, you still have the responsibility and you are speaking as the party who is responsible for the implementation. It's probably not the first time authority didn't match responsibility within your organization.

> What are some strategies for challenging the conclusions of area experts?

Challenging the conclusions of area experts is not going to do anything for your professional credibility or your career at the firm if it turns out that they are right and you are wrong. You are better off seeking clarifications from them. based on the facts of the case as you know them. If, after you get their clarifications and after you go over their weighing of the factors, their assumptions and their reasoning, you still find the conclusions problematic, consult the area experts again and if your concerns remain, write up your concerns to your management.